# How to directly type into a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are a lot of buttons in my HTML. And each time when I click on one button, that button is activated (other buttons are deactivated). And I want that, letters can be directly typed onto that specific button like a textbox (type="text"). Is that possible with javascript? Or do I need other things like JQuery, etc?? Thanks!

Comment: Please add your codes to question

Comment: Anything is possible with plain javascript, 'other things like jQuery' just make it easier.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```html
<button contenteditable="true">Foobar</button>
```

Comment: Be aware that `contenteditable` accepts unsanitized HTML so be careful about that.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to add an `input` element inside a `button` element.

For example:

```
   <button>
   <input type="text" placeholder="type somthing here" />    
    Send
   </button>
```

See the working version:
https://jsbin.com/lomufaqoxe/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap an input tag around a button tag and style it with CSS so that it merges with your button.